# Connection to large excel file is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, excel, connection

I have a very large excel file, it has about one milion rows and have size about 400MB.
I need to estabilish some System.Data.IDbConnection to this file. For now, i tried two aproaches:
1)

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='D:\\file.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';");
```

2)

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=<FILE>;ReadOnly=True;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"")
```

Both connections work just fine for small files (25MB). But even for 25MB file, opening connection take about 4seconds.

When I use 350MB file, this simple command:

```
connection.Open();
```

takes more than 3 minutes and i cannot use so slow connection.

Is there any free sollution to get fast IDbConnection for reading large excel file?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you either tried epplus which will take it in as XML or just using Linq??

Comment: No I didnt, but now i sure will. Thanks for help. Does it provides IDbConnection? .) I need it, becouse i need to process huge number of data in minimal time. I dont need effort of linq and such for now :)

Comment: For this amount of data, you would be better off loading the data into a relational DB and then using their native connections.

Comment: That is what i actually trying to do. i need to read all data, modify them and insert them into mssql db. I thought that using bulk copy class would be the fastest sollution

Comment: How many times do you want to do this? If you do it only once to import the data, why worry about 4min?

Comment: I need to process about 20 excel file every day. i need to parse data by some metadata rules, and slightly modify some of them. and it is not probably 4 minutes but much more. 4x20 is too many i think

Comment: Perhpas using [Linq2Excel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) might help you process the file.

Comment: ADO will evaluate the data to determine what is in the column.  You can tune that.  Also can import Excel directly using SSMS.

Comment: How could anything evaluate data in connection.Open() ? What if I just need to insert data or something (not my case)?

Comment: I looked up some big loads I did and had and fix for you but never mind.  ADO has to decide if is it string, integer, ...  Since Excel columns are not typed (like a SQL table) it has to sample the data to decide the type of the data in absence you supplying the type.   Are you currently declaring the datatypes of the columns?  You did say the connection takes a while - why do you think it takes a while?

Comment: Would loading the file into memory first improve performance? I find that it usually does if you have enough RAM available. There's an open-source package that will let you do that, discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262341/get-data-from-an-uploaded-excel-file-without-saving-to-file-system

Comment: No i am not declaring datatypes. How could i set this on IDbConnection? I dont understand, why opening connection try to resolve datatypes of columns, when i in this time actualy dont need this and it does not even know wich sheet i want to read, or such things

Comment: I mean, when I opening connection, i dont actually need any data. I need it after execution some reader query. It doesnt work that way??

Comment: @ItsJason - i want to load it in to memory, i quiet need it, but i would love to do that by some sequencial way - not to load all data in to memory, but load part, work with it, save it and move to next part.

Comment: @Magnus thanks for tip, but this project actually use same connection and for my purposes it is horrible slow, becouse it is using Reflection on each row read...

Comment: @ZlaBaba Ok, when I process Excel files I usually use [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) it costs money, but have been working out good. There is an evaluation you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different aproach, maybe if you use an access database, where de excel sheets are linked, you can gain time. The connection between access and excel is wierd but in many cases faster than import Excel files.