# Read Streaming Excel file which is not saving content to hard disk

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

i can comfortably read excel file via ADO.net and ExcelReader but i have to read an Excel file in which data is streaming(by some other application) and that data is not not getting saved on Hard disk

Problem is filestream reads content of file which is saved in hard disk :( but here data is not saved on hard disk

Task at Glance

1) Some exe named abc.exe (3rd party exe, i have no control over it) writing data to excel named temp.xls in every 1 second,and this excel file is open. We can see this data in excel but that data is not getting saved on hard disk. abc.exe is using excel just to display data where we can merely see data.

2) Now I am trying to read data from excel, since that data is not getting saved on hard disk so we can not read with help of file stream class.

3) I am looking for technique by which we can read data in C#  from this opened excel file directly from its memory not from hard disk.

Is it possible to read ?

Please help me out

Comment: check a similar post here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262341/get-data-from-an-uploaded-excel-file-without-saving-to-file-system

Comment: @sharmila, question you mentioned is focused on how to write in memory stream and my question is exactly opposite

Comment: Guyz please help me out

Comment: No it's not, you want to read the file without writing it into the hard disk, which can be done writing it into a Memory Stream.

Comment: I guess, i was not able to explain my question so edited now , problem is some 3rd party is displaying data in excel file. I have no control over it. i am making application to read this data at every 5 seconds

Comment: Am not able to understand your environment, some precision needed (a) "data is streaming(by some other application)" is it abc.exe ? (b) about "temp.xls" is it or not a real file on hard drive ? (c) about your point (2) do you get success in that reading ?

Comment: yeah abc.exe is streaming / displaying data in temp.xls , file is saved on hard disk but not current data , current data is displaying only in excel. No i have not got any success in reading , i am asking help how to read this data in C# application

Answer (score 0):

There is approch you can follow:

1. **open** *temp.xls* with **readonly** flag with standard way: [Workbooks.Open Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
2. Perform your traitement on data. Peraphs copying content to another Workbook.
3. **detect** changes on *temp.xls* using [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and reopen it as 1st point

Another thing can be useful is to detect end of process from abc.exe. Maybe it is only by detect non-existance of *temp.xls* or non-existance of abc.exe in table of process (via [ManagementEventWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx)).

Anyway at this point you should sniff everything passing thru *temp.xls*.

Answer (score 0):

IF you really want "live access" to those changes you can do this:

- Write an Excel-Addin (basically a PlugIn for Excel)
- It runs inside Excel and can receive events (like workbook/cell changed, file opened/closed etc.)...
- this AddIn then communicates all information needed via IPC (for example MMF) to your EXE

Another option might be to use Interop to communicate directly with Excel - whether this works robustly enought depends on several aspects (how the other EXE communicates with Excel etc.).