# Import excel to SharePoint 2010 custom forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint-2010, impersonation

I am having trouble in uploading the excel data to .Net forms deployed on SharePoint 2010 environment. The functionality is to upload the excel trough the .net forms and the excel will be saved to a location on the server. Once the excel is saved on the server the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider will fetch the data from the excel and upload it as comma separated values on .Net Text box control.

Here are the challenges we are facing currently.

1.) The functionality is only working when the user is logged in as a service account(higher permissions account) on SharePoint 2010.
2.) We tried logging in as a user account on SharePoint it did not work and was throwing the error below. I think this is mainly happening due to the permissions issue. We cannot assign all the users with service account permissions.

Is there a way where we can impersonate the login to service account to just complete the activity of uploading the excel and dispose the login of user account? Or any suggestions that will help me fix my issue?

**Error Message:**

Error Occured: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) at SegmentationTool.createSegment.btnFileUploadForDNIS_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Code:

```
strTarget = fileUploadForDNIS.FileName;

  string[] arrCheckExtension = strTarget.Split('.'); 
                    if (arrCheckExtension.Length >= 2)
                    {
                        if (arrCheckExtension[1].ToString().Equals("xls") || arrCheckExtension[1].ToString().Equals("xlsx"))
                        {
                            fileUploadForDNIS.SaveAs("B:\\Test\\" + strTarget);
                            strConnForExcel = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", "B:\\Test\\"+strTarget);
                            strQueryForExcel = String.Format("select dnis_id from [{0}$]", "oms_dnis");
                            OleDbDataAdapter adapForDNIS = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQueryForExcel, strConnForExcel);
                            dsForDNIS = new DataSet();
                            adapForDNIS.Fill(dsForDNIS);
                            if (dsForDNIS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < dsForDNIS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    if (strDNISids == "")
                                    {
                                        strDNISids += dsForDNIS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dnis_id"].ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        strDNISids += "," + dsForDNIS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dnis_id"].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                txtSpecAcquWinbackDNISForUpload.Text = strDNISids;
                                rdoMSCSpecificValue.Focus();
                                System.IO.File.Delete("B:\\Test\\" + strTarget);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Please Select File with .xls or xlsx Extension');</script>");
                            fileUploadForDNIS.Focus();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **System Account** is the user specified into IIS application pool, I suppose this user have permission to write to the **b:\test** folder, other user do not have this permission and for this reason operation fail.

You can use [RunWithElevatedPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) and the code run under the System Account privilege.

However I suggest you:

1) Use the [Microsoft OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) to read/write office files, better to use a wrapper library that simplify operations like [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) or [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

2) You can save the file into Document Library instead of file system (if you have multiple FrontEnd file system is not the better solution..)

3) From the code I see you you do not need to save the Excel, you can process the Excel file in memory (Stream) see point 1

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the response Max, I would like to change my code to store read the excel data and store it in memory stream and them process assign the excel data to a string. Currently i am facing lot of issues due to permissions while trying to save and read the excel from the SharePoint 2010 server file system. I appreciate you for directing me to the links above. But Can you please tell me if its possible to store data in memory stream and assign it to a string through C#?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262341/get-data-from-an-uploaded-excel-file-without-saving-to-file-system) for read excel from memory with ExcelDataReader, anyway is not clear what do you want to achieve.