# C# ASP.NET Generate and Email an Excel spreadsheet without saving it

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Good morning,

My host does not allow me to save files to the file system, but I would like to be able to send some reports via email as Excel attachments.

How can I generate and the file without actually saving it to disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you might get idea from this 
[How to write an Excel workbook to a MemoryStream in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156500/how-to-write-an-excel-workbook-to-a-memorystream-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your excel files in MemoryStreams and then attach them to the email before sending.

Comment: They want to know how to do it not what to do.