# Save an Open Excel WorkBook to Byte[]

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an open Exel workbook. One way to get Byte[] from it would be to save File using App.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (@temppath,..) and then read file to Byte[] from that path. But is there a way to read open workbook to Byte[]. I am using C#.

Answer (score 1):

This basically resolves to the question of how to get the workbook into a stream without saving it to disk first. See: [How to write an Excel workbook to a MemoryStream in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156500/how-to-write-an-excel-workbook-to-a-memorystream-in-net)