# How to write an Excel worksheet to a MemoryStream?

Tags: .net, excel

I have this code, but it saves to the file

```
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet sheet = app.ActiveSheet;
            sheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "login";
            sheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "e-mail";

            int row = 1;
            foreach (ProviderUser u in users)
            {
                row++;
                sheet.Cells[row, "A"] = u.UserName;
                sheet.Cells[row, "A"] = u.Email;
            }

            string pathToSave = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "users.xlsx");
            sheet.SaveAs(pathToSave);
            app.Quit();
```

Comment: That's not possible, Excel is an out-of-process COM server.  Its data is not directly accessible, you have to go through the namespace methods.  You can only ask it to save to a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write an Excel workbook to a MemoryStream in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156500/how-to-write-an-excel-workbook-to-a-memorystream-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the location of the file or do you need to create it using Excel first?

You can easily get the byte array of the file using

```
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToSave)
```

and then create your memory stream with the byte array:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

Is that what you mean?