# Convert excel file to byte array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, arrays, office-interop

I'm using ASP.net with VB codebehind.

I need to be able to convert an excel file created in code into a byte array in order to send it to the client. Without saving the file to the server.

this is how i created the excel document

```
Dim APP As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
Dim missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook = (APP.Workbooks.Add(missing))
Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Workbook.ActiveSheet

'..Fill cells in worksheet..
```

This is how i transmit it:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.Cookies.Clear()

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)
Response.CacheControl = "private"
Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", filebytes.Length.ToString())
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "cache")
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", 60)
Response.AppendHeader("Conetnt-Disposition", "attachement; filename='MostIssuesByModelReport.xlsx'; size=" & filebytes.Length.ToString() & "; creation-date=" & Date.Now.ToString("R") & "; modification-date=" & Date.Now.ToString("R") & "; read-date=" & Date.Now.ToString("R"))
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

'write to client
Response.BinaryWrite(filebytes)
Response.End()
```

I just need to get the content of `Workbook` into `filebytes`

EDIT:
After looking around a bit more I can now make it download a file, however this file does not use the filename specified in the above code, it uses the name of the asp server page that the user is on, it also has a .aspx extension..however if I force it to open in excel it is correct. Besides popping up saying the source may be corrupted. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The following link on SO may help you [convert-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application-to-byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534745/convert-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application-to-byte)

Comment: @RameshBabu This works slightly better, it does actually download a file, however the file is in the .aspx and has the same name as the page i ran the code on not the filename i specified in the response header

Comment: You have typos in the `Response.AppendHeader("Conetnt-Disposition",...` line.

Comment: You should *not* use the Office Interop libraries in an ASP.NET environment. It's probably not licensed for it, and it will probably break with lots of strange errors and use too many resources for what it needs to do. Instead, use a managed library such as Open XML SDK, NPOI, or EPPLUS (my favorite).